# Se puede descargar un archivo excel desde una web con javascript

Tags: javascript

Se puede descargar un archivo excel desde javascript si el sitio web requiere usuario y contraseña para ingresar a mis datos, y después ir a las opciones de reportes, seleccionar el reporte y descargarlo en Excel, específicamente esto lo podría hacer con javascript y al momento de ejecutarlo me descargaría automáticamente este reporte, o no hay esa posibilidad de "navegar" desde javascript por la web, así como se hace en testproyect dar una secuencia de comandos y parámetros de ingreso, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: al leer tu problema me di cuenta de lo que necesitas hacer es `web scraping` con `beautifulSoup` o `selenium`, para hacerlo `dinamicamente` e ingresar `credenciales` en las peticiones.